# Can Sphinx handle unicode normalization forms?

Tags: sphinx, unicode-normalization

I'm aware of the `charset_table` setting to allow `U+00E9 -> e` which will map 'é' to 'e'.  However if instead of U+00E9 you have U+0065 U+0301 (which is the "decomposed" form of 'é' which is just 'e' followed by an acute accent) then Sphinx will treat the U+0301 as whitespace and break up the word.

example:

```
mysql> CALL KEYWORDS('Crème brûlée', 'recipes_rt', 1);
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
| qpos | tokenized | normalized | docs | hits |
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
| 1    | creme     | creme      | 3    | 3    |
| 2    | brulee    | brulee     | 2    | 2    |
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> CALL KEYWORDS('Crème brûlée', 'recipes_rt', 1);
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
| qpos | tokenized | normalized | docs | hits |
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
| 1    | creme     | creme      | 3    | 3    |
| 2    | brule     | brule      | 0    | 0    |
| 3    | e         | e          | 3    | 3    |
+------+-----------+------------+------+------+
3 rows in set (0.15 sec)
```

Something like NFKC Unicode normalization is needed here, but I can't see any mention of that in the documentation.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how to handle it 'scalably' (ie all the forms), but the individuals could be probably be done with `regexp_filter`?

http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-regexp-filter.html

```
regexp_filter = \%u0065\%u0301 => e
```

---

Although having said that perhaps, just add **U+0301** (and other '[combining](http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/block/combining_diacritical_marks/index.htm)' chars) to `ignore_chars`?
http://sphinxsearch.com/docs/current/conf-ignore-chars.html

They disappear leaving jsut the 'unaccented' char (e)

Comment: Since I'm doing `é -> e` then I added `ignore_chars` to handle the combining characters.  However, I'm not sure which range is a "complete" set to handle all cases.  I also did the Combining Diacritical Marks (`ignore_chars = U+0300..U+036F`) like you mention, but not sure if that's complete.

Comment: fwiw the `regexp_filter` expression in this answer didnt work for me, I had to use this: `regexp_filter = \x{0065}\x{0301} => e`. I think this is because im using a later version of google re2? https://github.com/google/re2/wiki/Syntax